# Vue validator multiple input field

Tags: vue.js, vue-validator

how can i validate a form group (select + input text) that require at least one of the two with vue-validator.js?
Thanks..
e.g.

```
<select>
<option>Select one..</option>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="Or type here.." />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have select and input have the same v-model attribute and then set validation on one of them. like this:

```
<select v-model="modelName" v-validate:modelName="{required:true}">
<option>Select one..</option>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
<input v-model="modelName" type="text" placeholder="Or type here.." />
<span v-show="$validation.modelName.required">this field is required</span>
```

and of course all of your form should be wrapped in a validator component like this:

```
 <validator name="validation">
 </validator>
```

but i assume you're already doing this.